# Digital license for Office: are credentials required once the setup file has been provided?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-account, licensing, software-activation

I purchased a Digital License for MICROSOFT OFFICE 365/2019 PRO PLUS. It lets me install Office on 5 different devices. This license gives me a new account (let's call it "*My Account B*") which let me downloading the Office setup file.
I entered the page below and inserted the credentials of My Account B:

https://login.microsoftonline.com

I downloaded the setup file from this page (let's call it "*Setup File B*") and installed Office on a friend's laptop.

Now, want I want to do is to give my friend the opportunity to reinstall Office whenever he wants on the same laptop (in case he needs to format it in the future), without giving him the credentials of *My Account B*: I wonder if providing him the *Setup File B* whould be sufficient.

So my question is:

Does the Office installation file, once it has been downloaded through a Microsoft digital license, let users activating Office without inserting the account credentials every time?

Comment: Did you install Office 365, or did you install Office 2019? That's what makes the difference.

Comment: I installed Office 365

Comment: So you have a license to Office 365 not a perpetual Office 2019 license.  You would have to create a family organization, add your friend to that family, in order to share your Office 365 subscription with your friend.  You wouldn't have been able to share your Office 2019 license, you are only allowed, a single active installation with most perpetual Office licenses.